# How to map values from selected checkboxes to state using ngrx-forms?

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, ngrx, ngrx-store

I want to map selected checkboxes to state using `ngrx-forms`.

I have found similar [example](https://ngrx-forms-example-app-v2.herokuapp.com/valueBoxing), but it uses selects for outputting selected values.

[image]

**How can I change this example to use checkboxes instead of select, so that final result well be something like that?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the checkboxes it won't work and you need to write your own wrapper that listens to all of them, combines their states and updates the ngrx forms.